# Java Long Datatype converts to bigint type in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm doing a sample program to learn hibernate. One of the variable defined in an Entity is of type Java Long but when I startup application and when Hibernate tries to auto create table in Oracle database it generate create table script with type as `bigint`.

"`private Long pin`" converts to "`pin bigint`", since oracle doesn't support `bigint` datatype the scripts fails. I have added `dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect` to `hibernate.properties` file to generate SQL specific to Oracle. Is there anything else to be done?

Comment: Hmm unless you really use pin for any mathematical operations, you rather should use  BigDecimal datatype. Oracle's internal datatype NUMBER is much closer to BigDecimal then to Long. The advantage of Long is the speed of math. operations, but in case of most "NUMBERS" stored in databases the uniqueness is all you do care about.

Comment: I'm not using PIN for any mathematical operations. Just wanted to know what could be the reason. FYI, after changing it to BigDecimal table created just fine.

Comment: I do not know why hibernate behaves like that. Most of the databases store numbers in binary format (Mysql TINYINT, SMALLINT, BIGINT), Also Java's Long type is binary. Some databases are stored as decimal digits (MySQL's DECIMAL). Oracle has only one numeric datatype - NUMBER, and it stores digits the same way as Java BigDecimal.